# How can I have grid item elements displayed on one line?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm just starting to learn Material-ui,but when I used Grid, I got an error. This is my code.

My requirement is to put the header buttons on the same line, and if I zoom out it will appear as a scroll bar

```
      <Grid container spacing={1}>
        <Grid item xs={12} md={7}>
          <UserList></UserList>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
```

but i just get this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwjRk.png)

and  when i change my code :

```
       <Grid container xs={12} md={7} spacing={1}>
        <UserList></UserList>
      </Grid>
```

i can get what I wanted：
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WX3JW.png)

I know the prop `md` of `Grid` must be used on item.
But how do I write to get the results I want right?

I hope someone can help me！ thanks!

Comment: try giving ```direction='row'``` prop on the Grid container,
```<Grid container direction='row'>
        <Grid item xs={12} md={7}>
          <UserList></UserList>
        </Grid>
      </Grid> 
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it doesn't seem like what I want. It still doesn't show up on one line.

Comment: since you are trying to insert the buttons (search & +) maybe try using TableCell from Material UI. Also if possible post the minimal code in codesandbox .

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, you are allotting 7 columns for the grid item (i.e. your `<UserList />` component). Now, the header part which includes the search icon etc. is wrapping up in those 7 columns, I guess that's the way the header part is designed (may be with flex display), but the lower part i.e. the table has a fixed width and that's why it is overflowing and resulting in a horizontal scroll. It is behaving as expected.

In the second case, the way you have written the code does not make any sense about using grid layout, it is giving you what you finally need because it is like not using any grid layout at all, `<UserList />` is taking the whole width.

Please think about where you really want to use grid. Probably you don't actually want to put the whole component `<UserList />` as a grid item. Still, if you want to use only one item in the grid, you probably want to give `md={12}` to it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know what you mean.What I wanted was that the size of my table and the header buttons can shrink as the screen shrinks, so I used the md.What I want to know is why when I use MD, the hearder buttons gets squeezed into the bottom row when the screen shrinks .What I want is for those buttons to have a horizontal scroll bar like a table.  Like using 'display:inline' in css. (I tried adding that in styles, but it didn't work.) I hope you can see it and answer me thanks so much

Comment: Oh okay, in that case, please share the code related to the header part, if possible, the css for the header too. Unless you post what you have written, it is very difficult to figure out why it's not working the way you want it to.

Comment: Thank you very much and here is my code : [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-cohen-2pde0?file=/src/pages/userList/UserList.js).  I am so sorry maybe my code is very chaotic